# Trying to resize uploaded files as they are saved to server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I am using Glide to deliver image content from one of my sites. This is working well and I have now built a file upload so that admins can upload images to the site for subsequent download.

Some of the images that admins will upload will be much larger than I need (or want the overhead of storing on the server), so I want to downsize them, preferably during the upload routine or failing that, just after they have been saved to their new location (storage/app/images)

So, I've been hacking around with intervention for instance without much success because of my poor understanding of the file names and paths available from getClientOriginalName/Extension etc.

Could anyone show me a pattern for this which would work well. Ideally I'd love to include something like I've seen on others' examples like...

`$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);`

... in the correct place in my code

```
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $fileExtension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileMimeType = $file->getMimeType();
    if(in_array($fileExtension, $allowableExtensions)) {
      if(in_array($fileMimeType, $allowableMimes)) {
        array_push($dbFileList, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $newImage = '/images/' . $propertyCode . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::put('/images/' . $propertyCode . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
      }else{
        $errorMessage = 'At least one file was not an image, check your results...';
      }
    }else{
      $errorMessage = 'At least one file was not an image, check your results...';
    }
  }
```

## Update 1:

```
Storage::put('/images/' . $propertyCode . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
$img = Image::make($file);
Storage::put('/images/new/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $img);
```

This updated code outputs the files to the /new directory and all looks fine, but the output files have 'zero bytes'. What am I missing?

## Update 2: Final code

The final answer (after using the proper code provided by contributors) was that:

- I had to move my app from virtual box on to the dev machine (iMac) to prevent extra confusion with paths

  The path for the images must exist prior to making the ->save()

  The path variable must be set in advance of the ->save()

  I don't need the Storage::put at all, so the larger file never ends up on the server.

Then this final code started to work.

```
$path = storage_path('app/smallpics/')."/".$file->getClientOriginalName();
$img = Image::make($file)->resize(300,200)->save($path);
```

Much thanks to all of you. You make my Laravel learning curve a bit less terrifiying!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Intervention` to manipulate your image (resize etc.) as

```
$new_image = Image::make($file)->resize(300,200)->save('/path/to/save');
```

Comment: Thanks Nauman and @Mayank Pandeyz . I have tried doing as suggested. The solution gets me very close. My current code is as per #Update 1 above. This gives me a /new folder with the files contained, however, the files have 'zero bytes'. This is where my confusion lies. Do I use $file or file_get_contents($file) or something else? I can't figure what variable holds the actual file if that makes sense...

Comment: @Wittner, can you try `$new_image = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(300,200); `

Comment: I just tried that. Files are still zero byte. Echoing $file->getRealPath() gives '/tmp/phpBxgB8a' and similar for each file in the list. I have also tried file_get_contents($file) to no avail :-(

Comment: @Wittner, check the edit. To save that file you have to use  `save` method on image object.

Comment: Marking as correct because although others had correct contributions I feel that @Nauman Zafar had the exact answer and a lot of the other problems I was having were more to do with my inexperience with other parts of Laravel. Deep thanks to all though - I am indebted.

Answer (score 0):

The image upload and resize work flow is like:

- Upload the image from `tmp` to your directory.
- Make a copy of that image by setting the `height, width, quality` and save it in the same or some other directory.
- Delete the original image.

So as per your code flow:

```
Storage::put('/images/' . $propertyCode . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
```

after this code, put the image compress code and after that delete the original image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Intervention](https://github.com/Intervention/image) or just use [imagemagick convert command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) command for resize or convert.

Pay attention to comments :

```
public function saveUploadPic(Request $request)
  {
    $pic = $request->file('<NAME_OF_FILE_INPUT_IN_HTML_FORM>');

    #check for upload correctly
    if(!$pic->isValid())
    {
      throw new Exception("IMAGE NOT UPLOADED CORRECTLY");
    }

    #check for mime type and extention
    $ext = $pic->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $mime = $pic->getMimeType();
    if(!in_array($mime, $allowedMimeTypeArray) || !in_array($ext, $allowedExtArray))
    {
      throw new Exception("This Image Not Support");
    }
    #check for size
    $size = $pic->getClientSize() / 1024 / 1024;
    if($size > $allowedSize)
    {
      throw new Exception("Size Of Image Is More Than Support Size");
    }

    ########################YOU HAVE TWO OPTION HERE###################
    #1- save image in a temporary location with random hash for name if u need orginal image for other process
          #below code save image in <LARAVEL_APP_PATH>/storage/app/tmp/pics/
          $hash = md5(date("YmdHis").rand(1,10000));
          $pic->storeAs('tmp/pics', $hash.'.'.$ext);

          #Then resize or convert it
          $img = Image::make(storage_path('app/tmp/pics/'.$hash.'.'.$ext))->resize(300, 200);
          #save new image whatever u want 
          $img->save('<PATH_TO_SAVE_IMAGE>');
          #after u finish with orginal image delete it
          Storage::delete(storage_path('app/tmp/pics/'.$hash.'.'.$ext);

    #2- Or just use below for resize and save image witout need to save in temporary location
          $img = Image::make($pic->getRealPath())->resize(300,200);
          $img->save('<PATH_TO_SAVE_IMAGE>');
  }
```

if you want to use convert see [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/).

Comment: I have just been experimenting with yor code @Mr.Sun and I may be a bit closer. I was getting some strange errors, but this last one, 'Can't write image data to path (/home/vagrant/sites/ckgimages/storage/app/smallpics/)' makes me now think that my problems are stemming from the fact that my local app runs on a vagrant box and whereas Storage::put() places the images on my actual Mac drive, $file->storAs() puts the images on the Vagrant box. I'll have to move the app from Vagrant box to the main drive to experiment further...

Comment: Hi sorry for delay . I have no experience with MAC man but in my linux that work fine . I'll be glad to see your results

Comment: Your code got me looking more closely at GD and at how I handle my errors (I'm old school PHP moved recently-ish to OOP) and throwing exceptions is something I'm going to look more closely at. The upload part of this app will not be publicly visible as it's behind a login on an admin server, but the product itself is public facing and I'm using Glide to serve the photos to the public. I'll fire u a link to that when I'm finished if you'd like...

Comment: Mr. Sun apologies. I forgot to send that link. The public facing link is here:

http://www.irelandathome.com

and all property photos are taken coming from a separate image server on which I used Glide. I'm happy with the ability to resize on the fly and the backend is great for my admins to upload images for the property galleries.